# Avro Text file generated by Flume Twitter Agent not being read in Java

Tags: java, flume, avro, flume-ng, flume-twitter

**Not able to read and parse the File created by streaming twitter data using Flume twitter agent, neither using Java nor Avro Tools. My requirement is to convert the avro format into JSON format.**

When using either of the method, I get the exception : `org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40`

I am using Hadoop vanilla config in pseudo node cluster and the hadoop version is 2.7.1

Flume version is 1.6.0

The flume config file for twitter agent and the java code to parse the avro file is attached below :

```
TwitterAgent.sources=Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels=MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks=HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type=org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels=MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords=Modi,PMO,Narendra Modi,BJP

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:9000/user/ashish/Twitter_Data
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=100
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=30
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100
```

---

```
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.FileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.SeekableInput;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AvroReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/ashish/Twitter_Data/FlumeData.1449656815028");
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        SeekableInput input = new FsInput(path, config);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
        FileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader = DataFileReader.openReader(input, reader);

        for (GenericRecord datum : fileReader) {
            System.out.println("value = " + datum);
        }

        fileReader.close();
    }
}
```

Exception stack trace which I got is :

```
2015-12-09 17:48:19,291 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    value = {"id": "674535686809120768", "user_friends_count": 1260, "user_location": "ユウサリ", "user_description": "「テガミバチ」に登場するザジのbotです。追加してほしい言葉などの希望があればＤＭでお願いします。リムーブする際はブロックでお願いします。", "user_statuses_count": 47762, "user_followers_count": 1153, "user_name": "ザジ", "user_screen_name": "zazie_bot", "created_at": "2015-12-09T15:56:54Z", "text": "@ill_akane_bot お前、なんか、\u2026すっげー楽しそうだな\u2026", "retweet_count": 0, "retweeted": false, "in_reply_to_user_id": 204695477, "source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/twittbot.net\/\" rel=\"nofollow\">twittbot.net<\/a>", "in_reply_to_status_id": 674535430423887872, "media_url_https": null, "expanded_url": null}
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNextBlock(DataFileStream.java:275)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:197)
        at avro.AvroReader.main(AvroReader.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNextBlock(DataFileStream.java:266)
        ... 7 more
```

**Also do I need to give the Avro schema for the Avro file to be read correctly, if so where ?**

Comment: Forgot to add the output file stored in HDFS :

http://www.megafileupload.com/mq7i/FlumeData.1449730709818

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. Though I can see your data file which does not exist any more. I have checked this my data file which should be the same with yours.

I found my data file was already an avro container file that means it has its schema and data.

The avro file I got was very wrong because it should just include one head that contains avro schema, but actually it has multiple head in its file.

Another thing is tweets already are JSON format, why flume convert them to avro format?